# JSON array length

Tags: javascript, json

Here is my JSON array code

```
var App = [
 {
   "id": "123",
   "caption": "Test",
   "description": "Test Desc"
 },
 {
   "id": "345",
   "caption": "adsasdasd",
   "description": ""
 },
 {
   "id": "456",
   "caption": "adsasdasd",
   "description": ""
 },
 {
   "id": "578",
   "caption": "adsasdasd",
   "description": ""
 }
]
```

i tried with the following code

```
var obj = $.parseJSON(App);
alert(JSON.stringify(obj,4,null));
var AppLen = obj[i].length;
alert(AppLen);
```

but i didn't get any solution. Let me know if i missed any thing to get the JSON object array length.

Comment: where is question? can you explain wnat you want? anyway see [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length)

Comment: you need to use `obj.length` instead of `obj[i].length`

Answer (score 1):

your data is already json format:do like this

```
var App = [
           {
             "id": "123",
             "caption": "Test",
             "description": "Test Desc"
           },
           {
             "id": "345",
             "caption": "adsasdasd",
             "description": ""
           },
           {
             "id": "456",
             "caption": "adsasdasd",
             "description": ""
           },
           {
             "id": "578",
             "caption": "adsasdasd",
             "description": ""
           }
          ];

console.log(App);
console.log(App[0].length);// you can not get length from this because it is not array it's an object now.

var AppLen = App.length;
alert(AppLen);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
obj.size() or obj.length
```

If that dont run try this: [Length of a JavaScript object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5223/length-of-a-javascript-object-that-is-associative-array)

```
Object.size = function(obj) {
    var size = 0, key;
    for (key in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) size++;
    }
    return size;
};

// Get the size of an object
var size = Object.size(myArray);
```

Comment: There is not `.count()` neither for `Object`  nor for `Array`

Comment: Extending `Object.prototype` is a **very bad** practice, that can be compared to killing kittens or genocide.

Comment: @Ginden In this case it is not the `Object.prototype` but the `Object` itself. But yes neither the `prototype` nor the Object itself of a standard Object should be changed/modified unless it is a poly-fill.